# PList Types? Application/x-plist type

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, afnetworking

I am trying to use AFNetworking's AFPropertyListRequestOperation, however when I make an attempt to download it, I get an error

`Expected content type {(
    "application/x-plist"
)}, got application/xml"`

I did some research that application/xml is apparently the type that is created when it comes to iOS. How do I create a application/x-plist formatted PLIST? I tried doing plutil, but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the content type `application/xml` to the `AFPropertyListRequestOperation` using the method `addAcceptableContentTypes`:

```
[AFPropertyListRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/xml"];
```

Comment: ahh! jeez that's a much better solution. I have been trying to convert the file type for a while! This works great!

Comment: Thanks for that, you've saved me a good few hours. In my case the command required was for type @"text/plain". For reference, I was able to determine the Content-type of the response data (plist on a web server), using Charles (charlesproxy.com).